# How can I test my Express app without running a live server?

Tags: node.js, express, http, server

In many web frameworks, it is possible to perform integration testing on an app without spinning up a live server (see docs from [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/testing/#sending-requests-with-the-test-client), [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Testing/#benefits-of-using-fastifyinject) and [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#making-requests)). Simulating the network rather than actually sending requests over localhost can have a significant performance improvement. For example, in a [benchmark I made](https://github.com/MiguelGuthridge/best-test-request/actions/runs/5162068203), using Flask's test client was nearly 5x faster (3 seconds) than sending real requests with the `requests` library (14 seconds).

However, when using Express, I have not been able to find a way to achieve this. Tools such as [`supertest`](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest) appear to quietly start the server on an ephemeral port, rather than simulating the network.

How can I perform simulated requests to an Express server, rather than starting the server and requesting to it over localhost?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid testing an actual network request?  Isn't it a more accurate test of the actual system.  Actual networking behaviors beyond just a simple send of headers is involved in making requests, particularly requests with a body.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not contesting that sending real network requests is going to give a more accurate result, but it can be helpful to have tests run quickly, so I can get near-instantaneous feedback on my work. I don't believe that the difference is big enough to justify ruling out request injection, especially since it is supported by so many other frameworks. In Django, most integration test cases are performed using a simulated network, but it is simple to define test cases which should be performed on a live server, giving you accurate tests when needed, and the best CI performance otherwise.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to inject GET requests (no body).  All you have to do is build a fake `req` object with the appropriate properties set that correspond to the incoming GET request and you're done.  You can then call the appropriate request handler with that `req` object and a  test `res` object that can capture the response.

Comment: But, requests with a body need the body to be in a stream so some middleware can read that stream to do something appropriate to the incoming body in order to test that part of the implementation.  And responses that send a stream need more of a real `res` object implementation in order to behave properly.   For example, if the response so `someReadable.pipe(res)`, then you have to have enough of a real res that you can handle that.

Comment: @jfriend00 that looks promising, it's just a matter of finding a library that can imitate those `req` and `res` objects.

Comment: But, you'd also have to specify exactly what should be in those req and res objects.  The input is normally an http request and if you're not going to supply an http request, you have to somehow supply what would be parsed out of it so some code could then make a `req` object from that data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @jfriend00! I found a library that handles this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`light-my-request`](https://github.com/fastify/light-my-request) library, which is compatible with Express, as well as many other Node-based web frameworks.

```js
// server.js
import express, { json } from 'express';

const server = express();

server.use(json());

server.post('/my/route', (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  res.json({ greeting: `Hello, ${name}` });
});

export default server;
```

```js
// server.test.js
import server from './server.js';
import inject from 'light-my-requests';

test('Basic request', async () => {
  const response = await inject(server, {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/my/route',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    payload: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Miguel' }),
  };
  const json = JSON.parse(response.payload);
  expect(json).toStrictEqual({ greeting: 'Hello, Miguel' });
});
```

The performance is about 50% faster (4.3 seconds) than using the fetch API (6.5 seconds), at least in [the benchmark I ran](https://github.com/MiguelGuthridge/best-test-request/actions/runs/5164352402#summary-13979200546).